# Suspend and Hibernate does not work properly

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hibernate

I have a little Problem with my Ubuntu Setup. I have an Ubuntu 20.04 Installation with Gitlab and Nextcloud. Also i have a script which checks the CPU-Load every 15 minutes and set the System in Hibernate State when its not needed. To restart the System i use WakeOnLan in combination with my Router. Theses Settings work on my Notebook great. Yesterday i put the System hard disc in my old i5-750 Setup and reconfigured WOL on the new Ethernet Port. Unfortunately since i put the System hard disc there the suspend and the hibernate mode does not work.
When i do `sudo systemctl hibernate` the Screen of my Computer turns black and immediatly the login-Screen appears.
Maybe someone of you have a Tip for me to solve my problem.

My Ram and Swap Settings:
[RamAndSwap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAiOx.png)

[etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP6cQ.jpg)

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. How big are your RAM and swap-partition? please add the info to your original post with [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1284793/edit).

Comment: You have two swaps defined. Edit /etc/fstab and comment out /dev/dm-1 and reboot and retest.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried to do it but there ist no /dev/dm-1 line in the etc/fstab. I put a picture of the text of the etc/fstab in the Questien.

Comment: Now i comment "/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
" out. After "sudo swapon -s" there ist only the right swap file shown (After reboot). But the Hibernate and Suspend mode didnt work.